# ios,set uitabbarcontroller: Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation

Tags: ios6, window, uitabbarcontroller, deprecated

I have a button,with touch inside event. while I write following code to change the root viewController, the warning shows:`Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation`

```
- (IBAction)fn_login:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIWindow *window = delegate.window;
    rootTabViewController* rootVC = [[[rootTabViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    window.rootViewController = rootVC;
}
```

rootTabViewController is a UITabbarController.

if using UINavigationBar with UITabbarViewController, the warning is the same.

```
UINavigationController *navigationCtrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC] autorelease];
window.rootViewController = navigationCtrl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning rootViewController two time.
once at the time of allocating

```
    UINavigationController *navigationCtrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC] autorelease];

                                                                                     //^here
```

and second time

```
window.rootViewController = navigationCtrl;
      ^^here
```

no need to allocate two time. just remove last line

Comment: thank you, It's legacy code. but if there is no "window.rootViewController = navigationCtrl;" the navigationController will not show(viewcontrollers not switch), I need a uitabbar based UI, and only one navigation.

Comment: @meadlai: you can add like this [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];